# Chatterbot sqlite store in repl.it

Tags: python, sqlite, chatterbot, replit

I'm wondering how sqlite3 works when working in something like repl.it? I've been working on learning chatterbot on my own computer through Jupiter notebook. I'm a pretty amateur coder, and I have never worked with databases or SQL. When working from my own computer, I pretty much get the concept that when setting up a new bot with chatterbot, it creates a sqlite3 file, and then saves conversations to it to improve the chatbot. However, if I create a chatbot the same way only through repl.it and give lots of people the link, is the sqlite3 file saved online somewhere? Is it big enough to save lots of conversations from many people to really improve the bot well?

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with repl.it, but for all the answers you have asked the answer is yes. For example, I have made a simple web page that uses the chatterbot library. Then I used my own computer as a server using `ngrok` and gather training data from users.